# Understanding ladder PLC logic

Tags: plc, ladder, siemens

I'm trying to understand the flow logic of ladder language. Is it sequential like C/C++? "i don't think so"

Particular case: I've been trying to something very simple but cant make it happen as I want!
[image]
*Figure 1. ladder logic for counting and reset*
The timer never resets, I've tried with a lot of moving things around. Also, the coil is not blinking.

By the way (Q0.0 is 4 Hz coil).

I was trying with temp variable 'starting with #', but I read that it gets destroyed (I assume the networks running sequentially and in while(true) manner)?

```
ct0_reset       _______________________________________________
                             __________________________________
Tag counter > 4 _____________|  
                  _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
Out 0          __| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_

Tag counter up __|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|____
               ______________________________________________
cnfg_port    _|
```

*Figure 2. Timing diagram variables/coils*

comments asked about how the Q0.0 was done. here is the total code this is network 1 in (figure 1), and (figure 2) for blinking showing the total code.
[image]
*Figure 3. ladder logic for blinking*

**How i solved this:**
after many tries i did this: (although i feel its hard to read the logic here "i understand it" and "it works"). but i dont think its easy to read, so how would you do this?
[image]

i also edited blinking logic to the following (i feel this is more right):
[image]

Comment: Where is the logic for %Q0.0? Is that coil actually toggling?

Comment: yes its .. im not showing it here but its toggeling

Comment: I've added a timing diagram for you to edit. It's based on my best guess of what you're trying to do - but you never explained that in your question. Please edit to explain and correct the timing diagram.

Comment: @tyler added Q0.0 logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a latter version of TIA that allows mixing LAD and SCL you can add a simple code, instead of LAD:

```
IF Tag_Counter1 >= 5 THEN
         tmp_cnt0_reset := TRUE;
         cnfg_port :=  NOT  cnfg_port;      
ELSE 
         tmp_cnt0_reset := FALSE;

END_IF;
```

Regarding your code is totally wrong: Q0.7 is writen multiple times, as well M1.0.

You can also replace the CTU with SCL:

```
Out0_PosPulse := Out0 AND NOT Out0_pos; // Out0_pos ...static variable
Out0_pos := Out0;

IF tmp_cnt0_reset THEN
   Tag_Counter1 := 0;
ELSIF Out0_PosPulse THEN
   Tag_Counter1 += 1;
END_IF;
```

OR you might like the compact version:

```
Out0_PosPulse := Out0 AND NOT Out0_pos; // Out0_pos ...static variable
Out0_pos := Out0;

IF Out0_PosPulse THEN
   Tag_Counter1 += 1;
   IF Tag_Counter1 >= 5 THEN
       Tag_Counter1 := 0;
       cnfg_port :=  NOT  cnfg_port;  
   END_IF;
END_IF;
```

But there are still issues, Out0 and cnfg_port are PLC outputs, you shouldn't access them like any variable, you should only write into them. You have o use intermediate variables of type static or temp for that purpose.

You have a lot to learn about PLC programming.

Comment: hi @Marko Buršič , thanks for your reply, i can see SCL is text language which will make things much easier for me, but i wanted to know ladder as I'm going to debug programs that are written by someone else. so what do you think about network 1 (figure 3).

Comment: and also, i would ask why (you should'nt access outputs as read)? whats wrong with that? its exactly like a variable right?

Comment: would you mind to see my last edit (last picture) in my question since some can do "blinking" works but its not the right way of doing things..

Comment: "*... its exactly like a variable right?*" Yes but the program is scanning every few ms and the last occurrence of the coil determines the actual output at the end of each scan.

Answer (score 1):

> is it sequential like c/c++?

No, with typical column scan pattern* it is evaluated top-to-bottom and left-to-right. This means, first all of column 1 is evaluated from row 1 to end, then column 2 is evaluated, and so on.
Also, the last evaluation of a symbol overrides all earlier assignments.

You're writing Q0.7 twice, where line 2 is dominant. The inputs using Q0.7 use the same state.

**check manual of your plc to see what pattern yours uses.*

Comment: from my understanding about processors, (except FPGAs) all are sequential but ladder language is sequential in columns manner? so if i added "empty box" will it be a "nop" and it will pass which will control my logic flow in a row?

Comment: sorry, you dont have to answer as i feel the above question is lazy person who didnt done his research. i ll try it and search the internet, thanks.